# jQuery replace Start and End tag in html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have the following jQuery snippet which should replace a code such as [Button] Text Here [/Button] into something like:

```
<a class="button">Text Here</a>
```

The javascript I have is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var buttonStart = $("body").html().replace(/\[Button\]*/ig,'<a class="button">');
    $("body").html(buttonStart);

    var buttonEnd = $("body").html().replace(/\[\/Button\]*/ig,'</a>');
    $("body").html(buttonEnd);

});
```

The problem I am having is that it keeps replacing other elements on my page which have nothing to do with the Tags [Button] [/Button]. For insance the following:

```
  <div id="MiddleBarLeft"></div>
```

Also gets replaced into

```
  <a class="button"><div id="MiddleBarLeft"></div></a>
```

Shouldn't the Regex I have above just look for [Button] and [/Button] Tags?

Also, is there any other efficient way to go about this?

Thanks

=====================

Update.. this is my entire HTML file which replaces elements that have nothing to do with what I want to replace

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var buttonStart = $("body").html().replace(/\[Button\]/ig,'<a class="button">');
        $("body").html(buttonStart);

        var buttonEnd = $("body").html().replace(/\[\/Button\]/ig,'</a>');
        $("body").html(buttonEnd);

    });
    </script>


    <style>
    li{ 
    list-style:none;
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;}   

    .button, .button:visited {
        background: #222 url(overlay.png) repeat-x; 
        display: inline-block; 
        padding: 5px 10px 6px; 
        color: #fff; 
        text-decoration: none;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer
    }
    </style> 



    </head> 
        <body> 

     <div>          
           <ul>
            <li>[Button]Test[/Button]</li>
            <li></li>
            <li>Sample Text</li>
            </ul>
     </div>       


        </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: don't have time write a working answer right now. but **1.** you don't want to work on the whole body, **2.** you need to do the replace of `[Button]` and the corresponding `[/Button]` in one step. **3.** you should not have block elements  inside of an inline element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the way the replacement occurs - please consider the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GYrYa/

As you can see there are two buttons in the end, even though there's only one [Button][/Button] statement - it's because first you're replacing [Button] with `<a class='button'>` which creates an unmatched tag. This causes an `</a>` to be added at the end. Then you're replacing [/Button] with `</a>`, which creates another unmatched tag - this time `<a>`, at the end.

A better solution would be this:
http://jsfiddle.net/GYrYa/1/

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/GYrYa/2/ to omit script tag matching

EDIT 2: http://jsfiddle.net/GYrYa/5/ - final solution, incorporating @Rain Diao non-greedy matching

EDIT 3: Added performance test cases: http://jsperf.com/eithed-rsc3, please read the discussion below @Rain Diao's answer for the genesis of it

Comment: Yes thats right, thanks a lot for the explanation. Rain Diao's code snippet worked fine since the replace is being done all at one go. Thanks also for your code, looks better than parsing the entire body document!

Comment: Please, bear in mind that this will find all the tags, that contain given text, of the lowest level (so, doing something like `[Button][Button]A[/Button][/Button]` won't be possible) - updated the script a little as well (as it targeted the script tag): http://jsfiddle.net/GYrYa/2/

Comment: After some think over, reworked the solution to match only the textNodes, not the content of other nodes (if that makes sense) - previous solution wouldn't work for mixed content nodes.

Answer (score 1):

In actually, I did a quick testing, but cannot reproduce your problem. Please offer me more details, like an example.

two tips, ccouldimprove the performance:

1. remove the star in your RegExp. I think it was unneccessary.
2. call $('body').html(buttonReplaced) only once:

   ```
   var buttonReplaced = $("body").html()
                        .replace(/\[Button\]/ig,'<a class="button">')
                        .replace(/\[\/Button\]/ig,'</a>');
   $('body').html(buttonReplaced);
   ```
3. another solution:

   ```
   var buttonReplaced= $('body').html().replace(/\[Button\](.*?)\[\/Button\]/gi, '<a class="button">$1</a>');
   $('body').html(buttonReplaced);
   ```

Comment: Seems to work this way.. could it be that callng the replace seperately was screwing up the content? Thanks a lot!

Comment: eithed's explanation cleared up what was happeneing which makes perfect sense

Comment: yes, he explained the root cause, and I think it's right. but, I have to say, his solution is not as good as mine. first of all, his code cannot deal with more than one button tag. beside this, use `.*` in RegExp, could cause serious performance problem.

Comment: in actually, it's a very important feature of html5. please refer to http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#optional-tags I know author of jQuery is using this technique to reduce the code size. but it also cause some weird "bugs" frequently.

Comment: I don't know about efficiency, but if, let's say, there were events attached to the nodes, the solution of `$("body").html($("body").html())` is just simply not possible. I fully support the non greedy `.*?` though ;)

Comment: handle event with delegate, or just binding them after replaced the html. read/write dom is very expensive.

Comment: in terms of efficiency - wouldn't replacing the entire DOM be more memory expensive? (I truly don't know - but I guess rebuilding the entire tree...). I'd not suggest binding the events - ie. scenario where parts of site are loaded by ajax. Still - different solutions for different problems :)

Comment: greater number of times of DOM hurts the performance much more than larger scope. (same as SQL, one query with join server table is much faster than select from each table.) `body` here just be used as a container, of course, better to use something like `$('#container')`

Comment: This actually got me interested :D Though, test cases give me different result: http://jsperf.com/eithed-rsc3 (1/2 - for a standard kitchen sink DOM, with change of what runs first [if that would matter], 3 - for garbled / lots of nodes DOM). Probably should also test it on wide tree, but I should really start doing my official work :D

Comment: could you add your jsperf test case to your answer. I think it will be very helpful for other viewers. thanks for the discussing.

Comment: Thank you very much as well - sadly googling "performance search replacement jquery" doesn't give me anything, so if you have any links to where I can read about it, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use + instead of a star in your regex. As the first will match nothing as well

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var buttonStart = $("body").html().replace(/\[Button\]/ig,'<a class="button">');
    $("body").html(buttonStart);

    var buttonEnd = $("body").html().replace(/\[\/Button\]/ig,'</a>');
    $("body").html(buttonEnd);

});
```

Comment: this will just repeat the `]` which does not make much sens. also the `$("body").html(buttonStart);` will not have the expected result, because the browsers will automatically create a closing `</a>` somewhere, but not at the expected place. replacing `<a  >` and `</a>` must be do in one step.

Comment: It is still giving the same problem. It keeps replacing elements which have nothing to do with [Button] and [/Button]

Comment: So, is there a way to extract the text between the opening and closing tags.. for instance [Button] Capture Text Here [/Button] .. to manipulate Capture Text here and replace the tags in 1 line?

Comment: see the edit... I think this should work, though I am not confident about the extra </a>

Comment: Still did not work.. will edit my post to paste my entire html file

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BQkPp/ See here it is working for me. (also checked with generated source on local pc)

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this code `$("body").html(buttonEnd)`; will replace buttonStart. Mybe you shout try append() method, like this: `$("body").append(buttonEnd);`